# Error Subquery uses ungrouped column "i.colorid" from outer query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Following is the query

```
select (select description from Colors where ID = I.ColorID) AS Color,
O.Sono,
O.Customer,
SUM(L.Quantity) AS Quantity, 
O.shipdate,I.VapID,L.OrderID 
from Orderlines  L, Items I, Orders O 
where L.Item = I.SKU AND I.PanelID=3 
AND O.ID=L.OrderID 
AND O.OrderType = 'Sales Order' 
 AND (L.Status < 1 OR L.Status is Null) 
Order by Color, shipdate
```

This query is giving error 
"Subquery uses ungrouped column "i.colorid" from outer query"

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?
What's DBMS did you use?

Comment: there is no need for this subquery: (select description from Colors where ID = I.ColorID) - join to colors table and select directly from there

Comment: @D-Shih Valentina Studio is a DBMS

Comment: @DanielMarcus Yes i did that than it started giving following errors "Kernel error: ERROR:  column "c.description" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function"

Comment: This worked "select C.description,O.Sono,O.Customer,SUM(L.Quantity) AS Quantity, O.shipdate,I.VapID,L.OrderID from Orderlines  L, Items I, Orders O, Colors C where L.Item = I.SKU AND I.PanelID=1 AND O.ID=L.OrderID AND O.OrderType = 'Sales Order' AND (L.Status < 1 OR L.Status is Null) group by C.description, shipdate,o.sono,O.Customer, i.vapid, l.orderid order by C.description, shipdate"

Comment: ok try below solution

Comment: "Valentina Studio is a DBMS." What people are asking for is which concrete dialect of SQL you are writing. But _"valentina-studio is c++/QT cross-platfrom graphical database management and development software produced by Paradigma Software, Inc. for MySQL, MariaDB, SQLite, PostgreSQL and Microsoft SQL Server."_

Comment: @underscore_d that is postgresql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select  description  AS Color,
O.Sono,O.Customer,SUM(L.Quantity) AS Quantity, O.shipdate,I.VapID,L.OrderID 
from Orderlines  L, Items I, Orders O, colors c  
where L.Item = I.SKU AND I.PanelID=3 AND O.ID=L.OrderID AND O.OrderType = 'Sales Order' 
and  c.ID = I.ColorID
AND (L.Status < 1 OR L.Status is Null) 
group by description,
O.Sono,O.Customer, O.shipdate,I.VapID,L.OrderID
Order by Color, shipdate
```

Comment: description is giving ambigious error so i already did c.description that worked

Comment: What did you change, and how does that fix the problem?

Comment: sorry for late reply "select C.description as color,O.Sono,O.Customer,CAST(SUM(L.Quantity) AS VARCHAR) As Quantity,  CAST(O.shipdate AS VARCHAR),I.VapID,L.OrderID from Orderlines  L, Items I, Orders O, Colors C where L.Item = I.SKU AND I.PanelID=" + ID + " AND O.ID=L.OrderID AND O.OrderType = 'Sales Order' AND (L.Status < 1 OR L.Status is Null) group by C.description, shipdate,o.sono,O.Customer, i.vapid, l.orderid" this is my query